# Displaying different language issue

Tags: php, html, json

I am trying to display different language(turkish) but I can't display it while I can see it from my database in HTML but I can't display when I echo turkish characters ç ğ ı ö ş ü  it displays like § ❢ ₳ ₢ in PHP. While the file should stay in PHP because I am using it for iOS. So please where would be my problem?

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);

$queryA = '';
$decision = $_GET['x'];
$ilParam = $_GET['y'];


$ilSecim = 0;
$ilceSecim = 1;


//Check to see if we can connect to the server
if(!$connection)
{
    die("Database server connection failed.");  
}
else
{

//Attempt to select the database
        $dbconnect = mysql_select_db($db, $connection);

        //Check to see if we could select the database
        if(!$dbconnect)
        {
            die("Unable to connect to the specified database!");
        }
        else
        {          
      if($decision == $ilSecim)
        $queryA = "SELECT distinct city FROM places";

            $resultset = mysql_query($queryA, $connection);

            $records = array();

            //Loop through all our records and add them to our array
            while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultset))
            {
                $records[] = $r;
            }

            //Output the data as JSON
            echo utf8_decode(json_encode($records));
        }
 }
?>
```

Comment: when you say "I can see it from my database in HTML " do you mean you have html data in db thus $records contain html or that you use a web client like phpmyadmin to view the data?

Comment: @melc
No, I have crated a file from HTML and PHP and I used `meta` and it works. but I need the file to be PHP not HTML.

Comment: You probably have a character encoding problem. Check the PHP documentation on character encodings. If problems remain, provide sufficient data to actually reconstruct the problem and explain what the problem is (“I can't display it” is not a prroblem description).

Comment: Perhaps you'll still need to set the character set for the database connection.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I am trying to echo turkish characters ç ğ ı ö ş ü but  when I echo it, it displays like § ❢ ₳ ₢ . That what I mean I can't display it. Sorry for bad description!!

Comment: @LuaiKalkatawi I think your problem is with character encoding :) I'll write you an answer

Comment: just a question: 
The data are okay after you pull them out of database? For example output the data through var_dump($records) instead of json, just to see how it would look

Comment: @mishan still same problem... but some alphabet works for example Ç, Ğ, İ, Ö, Ş, Ü, ı == Ç, ?, ?, Ö, ?, Ü, ? . So ı, Ğ, İ, and Ş doesn't work. But the JSON formate is different.

Comment: :) check my answer, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, when pulling data of the database, whether the special characters remain good depends on the character encoding.

### WHAT IS CHARACTER ENCODING

Imagine character encoding as a big table, where every character has his numeric representation - for example something like:

```
A = 1
B = 2
C = 3
..et cetera..
```

Based on different cultures and needs, there are lots and lots of different encoding tables, one being US-ASCII, other for example utf8 or utf8_czech, or utf16 and they each give different characters different numerical value (usually in different numeral system like hexadecimal etc.)

### Explanation

And now imagine, that you have text, encoded in one type of encoding, that is stored in database in a table. You create a database connection, which doesn't know the character encoding of the table/column and because it had not been told what character encoding to use, it used the default one.

Now you use a query to pull the data out of the table and read them, but since the database connection doesn't know the right encoding, it uses the default one, which is close to the one you use, but not close enough.

Because as it reads the character codes from database, it reads them according to it's default character encoding and gives them different meaning - from ç becomes § et cetera...

### Solution

So basically, what you need to do is specify the character encoding of the database connection. It is done by adding `mysql_set_charset` function;

```
mysql_set_charset("charset_name_you_want_to_use",$database_connection_name);
```

**In your case:**

```
mysql_set_charset("charset_name",$connection);
```

Just put the name of the character set used in your database instead of `"charset_name"` and put it somewhere inside your code, preferrably after you select a database.

You should also know, that you are using a part of PHP, that will be probably soon deprecated and if you're working on PHP server with version higher than 5.0 you should use some other alternative to **mysql** functions like **mysqli** (both of them work with mysql databases, mysqli is just a newer and preferred way).

P.S.: I tried to be as precise as I can, but PHP is not my thing even though i have some basic experience with it. :)

Comment: I have tried it but it is still not working I have put it before and after SELECT database. Thanks again for you help.

Comment: what character set are you using in the table?

Comment: I have used utf8_general_ci and I have used utf8_turkish_ci but same result. I mentioned that even out of database I can't echo turkish character in empty php file.

Comment: try just setting `utf8` and see what comes out.

Comment: When I made it `UTF-8` it becomes like that Ã‡, Äž, Ä°, Ã–, Åž, Ãœ, Ä±

Comment: and what character encoding are you using in your database?

Comment: I am using utf8_general_ci in database

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39353/discussion-between-luai-kalkatawi-and-mishan)

Answer (score 0):

A nice simple implementation found in http://www.happycode.info/php-json-response/
I'll post it here in case it disappears

```
<?php

/**
* http://www.happycode.info
*/

function jsonResponse($param, $print = false, $header = true) {
    if (is_array($param)) {
        $out = array(
            'success' => true
        );

        if (is_array($param['data'])) {
            $out['data'] = $param['data'];
            unset($param['data']);
            $out = array_merge($out, $param);
        } else {
            $out['data'] = $param;
        }

    } else if (is_bool($param)) {
        $out = array(
            'success' => $param
        );
    } else {
        $out = array(
            'success' => false,
            'errors' => array(
                'reason' => $param
            )
        );
    }

    $out = json_encode($out);

    if ($print) {
        if ($header) header('Content-type: application/json');

        echo $out;
        return;
    }

    return $out;
}

?>
```

Parameters:

$param
Array or string to output.

$print
Should the output be printed or returned. Default behavior is to return.

$header
Should it send content type header or not. Default behavior is to send.

**example 1**

```
$response = array(
    array('id' => '1', 'name' => 'some name 1', 'created' => '2010-06-29 11:41:27', 'editable' => '1'),
    array('id' => '2', 'name' => 'some name 2', 'created' => '2010-07-07 16:47:03', 'editable' => '1'),
    array('id' => '3', 'name' => 'some name 3', 'created' => '2010-08-30 09:23:38', 'editable' => '1')
);
die(jsonResponse($response));
```

output

```
{
    "success":true,
    "data":[
        {"id":"1","name":"some name 1","created":"2010-06-29 11:41:27","editable":"1"},
        {"id":"2","name":"some name 2","created":"2010-07-07 16:47:03","editable":"0"},
        {"id":"3","name":"some name 3","created":"2010-08-30 09:23:38","editable":"0"}
    ]
}
```

**example 2** to return error

```
$error = 'Operation not permitted.';
die(jsonResponse($error));
```

output

```
{
    "success":false,
    "errors":{
        "reason": "Operation not permitted."
    }
}
```

This way you can test it by printing or not from the second parameter.